# Android Slow File Download vs iOS & BlackBerry - DefaultHttpClient

Tags: android, download, httpresponse

I am using the following code to download files, and I am finding that the performance is really really slow compared with virtually the same code on iOS and BlackBerry.

As well as testing on various different SDK versions and OSX vs Windows, I have also tried the App on various devices - HTC Desire, Samsung Galaxy, Huwei Pulse, HTC Wildfire - all with terrible performance vs. iPhone and BlackBerry devices.

Check out this video I made to compare the speeds on the 3 emulators:
  [Android vs. iOS and BlackBerry](http://mepubli.sh/iOSvsAndroidVsBB.mp4)

Here is the Android code:

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
InputStream input = null;

try {   
fos = new FileOutputStream("XXXX");

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("XXXX");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        input = response.getEntity().getContent();    

byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int readBytes;
while (((readBytes = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1)
&& !thePackage.getPackageStatus().equals(
PackageStatus.STATUS_CANCEL_DOWNLOAD)) {
fos.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
}
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
if (fos != null) {
try {
fos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
}

if (input != null) {
try {
input.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
}

    }
}
```

I've tried BufferedHttpEntity and other buffering/threading strategies, but this version of the code is the best performing out of any of the different options we've tried. I've run extensive code profiling, and can't see too much time being lost between the top level functions and the native code in Dalvik/Apache Harmony.

Any ideas would be fantastic, because the bad performance is making our application virtually unusable.

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: ..just a thought, 'cos I  don't have any android. What is the typical readBytes value returned?  I've been bitten by that sort of thing before on other apps/systems - allocate a big buffer, system read call insists on returning just a few bytes for each call resulting in inefficient buffer use and excessive disk writes.

Comment: Oh - and can't see where buffer gets freed - does android have a GC?

Comment: Hi Nick, I assume you're doing this in a service or a background thread?

Comment: android emulator is far from being a fast machine. Good android devices perform far better.

Answer (score 2):

The android documentations states that the FileOutputStream is not buffered and should be wrapped in a BufferedOutputStream.

```
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("XXXX"));

        // write to out

    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }

    }
```

More info at [FileOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)

Comment: Nick, you should also consider holding a wakelock if the download could last long enough for the device to go back to sleep. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html

Comment: This is particularly important when writing to flash, as you want to minimize the number of write operations.

Comment: BufferedOutputStream adds an 8192 byte buffer, which is pretty much irrelevant seeing as I'm using a buffer that size anyway, and the HTTP reads are filling that buffer anyway. It makes no difference to performance (slight negative performance impact).

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten this answer, after talking to Nick in person (in September 2011), he stated that on a real device there was no issue.

The issue appears to be performance differences between the emulator and real hardware. He also checked he wasn't using the throttling.

I've never tried downloading large files using the emulator so I can't comment, other than to say Nick is happy now ;-)

Comment: Hi Oli, I'm aware of the network throttle, but I've got it set to 'full'. I've tried it on HSDPA and 3G too, and compared to real on-device testing speeds on my iPhone (on 3G) and the throttle makes little or no difference... the download speed is always bad on the Android.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of [options](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/params/HttpParams.html) for the connection.
you may try to set some of them yourself
or
try to use [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html)